# O que é operação bit-a-bit?

Tags: bit

Já li algumas coisas aqui no Stack Overflow, mas não entendi muito bem.

O que é operação bit-a-bit?

Por exemplo, no contexto:

> Considerando a operação bit-a-bit 15^3, o resultado será:

Comment: Dê um contexto.

Comment: Editado, Maniero!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho é uma operação feita com os bits das variáveis, não com seus valores inteiros

Comment: Relacionadas: [Operador “ | ” em Java](/q/34292/5878) | [O que significa o operador “|=” em Python?](/q/238219/5878)

Comment: É só o operador? Sério?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explicação

A questão é: O que significa `15 ^ 3` ou `15 xor 3` bit a bit?

Primeiro convertemos 15 e 3 da base decimal em base binária:

```
15 : 1111
 3 : 0011
```

Como funciona o XOR?

Xor ou OR Exclusive (ou exclusivo) é verdadeiro se os bits A B são diferentes e falso se são iguais, o que dá essa tabela

```
A B  XOR
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 0
```

Agora você tem que emparelhar o 3 e o 15 binário na vertical e proceder a operação XOR bit à bit

```
Bit  A B  XOR
1    1 1 | 0 
2    1 1 | 0
3    1 0 | 1
4    1 0 | 1
```

Ou seja, o resultado de `0b1111 xor 0b0011` é `0b1100`, em decimal é 12.

Comment: Agora entendi! Obrigado, William!